# 'Table' tag is not recognized

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

Trying to use the `<Table>` in my `.xaml`, using the instructions in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750416(v=vs.110).aspx) 
However, the table is not recognized and I get this error:

> Invalid Markup

[image]

- Should I add any `using` statement in the `.xaml.cs` code?
- Should I add any assembly references to my project?

**Note** I created the project in Visual Studio using the *"Pivot App (Windows Phone)"* template.

- Is it even possible to use `<Table>` in this project?
- If Tables are not supported in Windows Phone Projects, what are the other options?

Comment: can you show us your full xaml

Comment: There is no table in XAML for windows phone.  I would use a grid instead.  You can add rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Table>` is not provided in in windows phone project or even UWP project.
You should try using [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid). This article shows how to use the Gird control: [How to: Add Rows and Columns to a Grid](http://Gridhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525(v=vs.110).aspx)